# Scripting: Get object transformation for every render frame (depsgraph issue)

Tags: python, scripting

Whenever an animation is rendered, I want to extract the camera transformation matrix and save it to a file. My problem is that the transformation is not updated during render. This is a known issue and after some search I figured out that I have to use the depsgraph to retrieve the information. The problem is that neither `render_pre` nor `render_post` have the depsgraph argument.

So what is the correct way to retrieve object data in one of those application handlers? Am I supposed to register for `depsgraph_update_post` and store the information in a member until needed?

Comment: @batFINGER I tried both 2.8 and 2.9 alpha - `frame_change_post` has a depsgraph argument but this also gets called when manually using the timeline and not just during render.

Comment: @batFINGER As said above **frame_change**_post is called when manually using the timeline. That's why I want to use **render**_post.

Comment: Sorry about that Twas late, can see the diff between render and frame change now.